# quartz scheduler in clustered environment

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

We are using quartz scheduler  and my requirement is to run Job in each server in clustered environment . We have 2 server configured in clustered environment . for example if Job is schedule for 8PM then it should start at both the server .

Comment: possible duplicate of [Quartz scheduler in cluster environment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12626380/quartz-scheduler-in-cluster-environment)

Comment: Then what is the need for cluster? Cluster is required to load balance I mean start the job in on server based on load.

Comment: so if I will set org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered = false , will it cause Job will be execusted in both the severs ?

Comment: You need to run a separate (non clustered) quartz scheduler on each server

Comment: we already have 4 job configured with clustered scheduler and the new Job requirement is to make it non clustered . so we will need 2 scheduler clustered and non-clustered in the same JVM . is this is the only solution ?

Comment: any advice on above ?

Comment: i tired with org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered = false and RAMJobStore but it didn't work for me

Comment: i tired with org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered = false and RAMJobStore but it didn't work for me . any advice ...

Comment: can you post your config , also explain what didnt work ?