# Quartz with spring - clustered environment

Tags: spring-mvc, quartz-scheduler, quartz

I'm using old version of quartz (2.1.2) with spring 3.1.0.
I have simple configuration that should prevent parallel job execution:

```
<bean id="schedulerFactoryBean" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobFactory">
        <bean class="com.azdne.infrastructure.schedule.ScheduledMethodJobFactory" />
    </property>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="schedulerDataSource" />
    <property name="quartzProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName">scheduler-cluster</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass">org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered">true</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount">4</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId">AUTO</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.skipUpdateCheck">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

'threadCount' is set to 4 because I have more jobs to execute at scheduled time.
I have also annotated my job class with @DisallowConcurrentExecution:

```
@Component 
@DisallowConcurrentExecution
public class MyJob{
   @Transactional(timeout=900)
   @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 2 * * ?")
   public void execute() {
   ... implementation goes here
   }
}
```

Job can be started from one of two different server nodes that uses the same database for configuration purposes and data processing. Unfortunatelly my task **sometimes** starts on both of them. Sample application logs:

```
NODE 1: task-executor.log.2017-05-16.gz:16/05/2017 02:00:00.068 [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_Worker-3] INFO  com.package.schedule.job.MyJob.execute - MyJob job - start

NODE 2: task-executor.log.2017-05-16.gz:16/05/2017 02:00:00.103 [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_Worker-1] INFO  com.package.schedule.job.MyJob.execute - MyJob job - start
```

This is unusual situation. Sometimes job starts on both machines, sometimes only on one. I have checked my application logs and didnt find any errors during data processing. Sometimes gap between job start is small - milliseconds, sometimes its seconds. **Where should I look for mistake? Am I missing something in configuration?**

Answer (score 2):

It could be about clock drift. You need to make sure that the clocks are synchronized between every nodes.

source:
http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/configuration/ConfigJDBCJobStoreClustering.html
and
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12629332/7321097